# Inconsistent font baseline on Linux for some fonts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts

Some fonts on Linux render like in the picture, i.e. some characters are higher up/lower down than others. Is this due to bad rendering or a bad font? Any tips to fix it? (In case it helps: I took the screen shot on Firefox, but Chrome renders the font the same way)

[image: Font rendering on Linux/Firefox]

Comment: Can you share a link with the messed up fonts?

Comment: Sure, just go to http://www.corriere.it

Comment: looks fine on my fedora-22 and centos 6 machines at work. I'll try my ubuntu when I get home.

Comment: It looks messed up on my ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

The font in question is called solferino and can be downloaded [here](http://static2.corriereobjects.it/includes2013/LIBS/css/fonts/solferino/%5EClferinotext-bold-webfont.ttf) (may be copyrighted). You can download the `ttf` file to `~/.fonts/` to install for yourself. You can then use the font in your applications, for example in OpenOffice. By changing the font size in your application, you can find certain sizes where the base line is not aligned and other sizes where it is aligned. This appears to be a "feature" of the font itself. Since your browser downloads the font while rendering the page, you can not override it. However, you can use your browser's zoom function to find a size where the baseline is straight. In my browser, that's 90% zoom. In OpenOffice for example 32pt is messed up but 36pt is fine. It just seems to be a fault of the font developer.

Comment: As far as I know the font has been created specifically for the newspaper site, and I'd bet they tested rendering only on Windows and Mac.